# simple csv QA with langchain does not give all answers

Tags: csv, langchain

I have this very simple film.csv file

```
year:1999,author:A,film:FilmA,Description:"ac abs moon"
year:1998,author:B,film:FilmB,Description:"yes"
year:1999,author:C,film:filmC,Description:"No"
year:1996,author:D,film:FilmD,Description:"MUST SEE"
```

I have this simple langchain based QA code

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.document_loaders.csv_loader import CSVLoader
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

load_dotenv()
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

csvloader = CSVLoader("wiki_as_csv/film.csv")
csvdocuments=csvloader.load()

search = Chroma.from_documents(csvdocuments, embeddings)


chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.3), 
                                   retriever=search.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1}),
                                   return_source_documents=True)
result = chain({"question": "from the input file , which are all  the authors that have a film in 1999", 'chat_history': ""}, return_only_outputs=True)
print("Answer: ", result["answer"])
```

Unfortunalely , the answer I get is :
**From the input file, the author "A" has a film in 1999.**

Why doesn't it see Author C ?

Thx by advance

Comment: did you try to set k more than 1 in `search_kwargs={"k": 1}` ?

Comment: Good answer simpleApp
Thx , please post an answer so that I can vote for 
cheers